# Node js fs.exists only searching file in current directory

Tags: node.js

I have setup process.env.path variables and fs.exists(fileName). Node is not able to find the file if it is not in its currently directory.
 Is there someway i can configure node to search for file in all directory mentioned in 'process.env.path'.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported out of the box. You will have to find a suitable npm package that already does this for you or write your own code. Something along the lines of the code that is in [node-whereis](https://github.com/gfauchart/node-whereis):

```
var fs = require('fs');

function whereIsMyFile(filename){
    var pathSep = process.platform === 'win32' ? ';' : ':';

    var directories = process.env.PATH.split(pathSep);
    for (var i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
        var path = directories[i] + '/' + filename;
        if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
            return path;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```